# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop.php on line 6

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Xammp server and I have written below php code for create table  and this gives me syntax error

```
<?php
$con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

create table customer(
        cust_id int primary key,
        name varchar(255) ,
        Email varchar(255) 
);
?>
```

Error

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop.php on line 6

Comment: Are you trying to create a new database table?

Comment: Did you know about PHP or you are a beginner.

Comment: yes I am a beginner

Comment: I am trying to create new table in database. I have already created a database.

Comment: You cannot just put code in another language (SQL) just plain into your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the query into a variable.

```
$sql = "create table customer(
        cust_id int primary key,
        name varchar(255) ,
        Email varchar(255) 
        )";
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the create table syntax into variable and then excute it with 
mysqli_query

```
<?php
$con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');

$sql = "create table customer(
    cust_id int primary key,
    name varchar(255) ,
    Email varchar(255) 
);";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){  
     echo "Table created successfully";  
} else {  
    echo "Table is not created successfully ";  
}  
?>
```

this this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_create_tables.htm